# codeigniter sum quantity from multi tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have problem in my SQL query for getting correct sum values, I'm showing my database tables please any one help about this problem.

```
stock
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
|  stock_id   | order_id  |   stock_series |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
|        25   |        7  |          10001 |
|        26   |        7  |          10002 |
|        27   |        7  |          10003 |
|        28   |        9  |          10004 |
|        29   |        9  |          10005 |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+

stock_details
+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|  stock_id   | order_id  |       item_id  |  item_rcv_qty  |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|        25   |        7  |           3    |          2     |
|        25   |        7  |           1    |         10     |
|        26   |        7  |           1    |          3     |
|        27   |        7  |           1    |          2     |
|        28   |        9  |           4    |          5     |
|        28   |        9  |           1    |          5     |
|        29   |        9  |           4    |          5     |
|        29   |        9  |           1    |          5     |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+

purchase_orders_details
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
|  order_id   |  item_id  |      item_qty  |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
|         7   |        1  |           2    |
|         8   |        1  |           5    |
|         7   |        1  |          10    |
|         9   |        1  |          10    |
|         7   |        3  |          10    |
|         9   |        4  |          20    |
+-------------+-----------+----------------+
```

my code-igniter code is below,

```
$stock_id = 25;

$result = $this->db->select('
        s.stock_id,
        st.item_id,
        SUM(pd.item_qty) AS item_qty,
        SUM(st.item_rcv_qty) AS rcv_qty
    ')->from('stock s')
            ->join('stock_details st', 'st.stock_id = s.stock_id', 'left')
            ->join('purchase_orders_details pd', 'pd.order_id = st.order_id AND pd.item_id = st.item_id', 'left')
            ->group_by(array('st.item_id', 'st.stock_id'))
            ->where('s.stock_id', $stock_id)
            ->get();
    $count = $result->num_rows();
    if($count > 0){
        $result = $result->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

return result is

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [stock_id] => 25
        [item_id] => 1
        [item_qty] => 15
        [rcv_qty] => 20
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [stock_id] => 25
        [item_id] => 3
        [item_qty] => 2
        [rcv_qty] => 2
    )

)
```

`rcv_qty` must be 10 but here in array `rcv_qty` is `10` you can see in my database table `stock_details` 2nd row `stock_id` is `25` and `item_rcv_qty` is `10` but in array showing 20

Please any one solve this problem
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this is that when you join `stock_details` on `purchase_orders_details` table, there are 2 records in the `purchase_orders_details` corresponding to `stock_id=25`, therefore the `SUM(st.item_rcv_qty)` will run on 2 records, not just 1, summing up `item_rcv_qty` twice.

If you have only 1 record in `stock_details` for each `stock_id` - `order_id` combination (as shown in the sample data), then just use min() / max() / any_data() function in place of the sum() on that column to get the 10 back:

```
$result = $this->db->select('
        s.stock_id,
        st.item_id,
        SUM(pd.item_qty) AS item_qty,
        MAX(st.item_rcv_qty) AS rcv_qty
    ')...
```